# Express4 how to return multiple function in single module.exports function

Tags: node.js, express

My Model Code is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(){
    'use strict';
    return {
        getAllUsers : getAllUsers,
        getWatchlists : getWatchlists,
        getUserBidDetails : getUserBidDetails,
        addToWatchlist : addToWatchlist,
        removeFromWatchlist : removeFromWatchlist,
        getUserBuyingLimit : getUserBuyingLimit,
        userBidDetails : userBidDetails,
        getUserWatchlists : getUserWatchlists
   };   
}
```

I have defined all the functions which we are returning in module.exports, but when the last function i.e "getUserWatchlists" get called then it is throwing an error

```
Error: has no method 'getUserWatchlists'
```

Might be i am not using the correct way to return multiple function  in single module.exports function. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just set `module.exports` to the object that you're currently returning? For example:

```
module.exports = {
  getAllUsers: getAllUsers,
  getWatchlists: getWatchlists,
  getUserBidDetails: getUserBidDetails,
  addToWatchlist: addToWatchlist,
  removeFromWatchlist: removeFromWatchlist,
  getUserBuyingLimit: getUserBuyingLimit,
  userBidDetails: userBidDetails,
  getUserWatchlists: getUserWatchlists
};
```

Alternatively if you want to avoid duplicating the names like that, you could just set the functions on the `exports` object and avoid re-assigning `module.exports` at all. For example:

```
exports.getAllUsers = function getAllUsers(...) {
  // ...
};

exports.getWatchlists = function getWatchlists(...) {
  // ...
};

// ... etc.
```

Comment: Working fine, Thanks for the suggestion